# About feed sparse matrix into the graph

Tags: tensorflow

For the data dimension is too large, i have to change the data into sparse matrix, instead of the dense array.

However, for the graph includes the cnn, and when i feed the sparse matrix directly, i was told the cnn cannot receive the sparse tensor. so i have to do the operation 'sparse to dense' at first.

But the question is that the data(multi sparse matrix)  i feed should be converted to a two-dimension sparse matrix.(e.g i have sparse matrix1, dim is [14,25500],and sparse matrix2, dim is [14,25500], the perfect dimension i want to feed is [2,14,25500], but the reality i faced is [28,25500])
So i have to split the tensor after entering the graph.

i want to ask, if any other ways can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tf.stack* is your friend

```
tf.stack([matrix1, matrix2]) # => [2,14,25500]
```

Comment: um, i think it is a better way to connect the two matrix, instead of recurrent spliting and 'expand_dims', thanks a lot.
but what frustrates me a lot is that i have 3600 sparse matrix, dims = [14,25500], what's more, i have to use 'sparse to value' so that i can feed. But i get no way to feed the 3600*14*25500 sparse matrix into the graph, unless i use the 'scipy.sparse_matrix.vstack' to change it into [3600*14,25500], and then feed this into graph, but if i do so, i have to split this lengthy tensor at first after i feed it into the graph

Comment: Please accept the answer and if you have another question, feel free to ask it in another question in stackoverflow. Don&#39;t forget to read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).